# Pupetter Aria Selectors Frame Support

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility, puppeteer, chromium

I've been playing with the Aria selectors https://developer.chrome.com/blog/puppetaria/ and with `page.accessibility.snapshot()`. Both pierce shadown-doms but neither pierce frames. I found a design doc that states this was a deliberate decision (along with a question mark).

For the aria selector it's a pain but you can work around it by using page.frames()..$()

For `page.accessibility.snapshot()` there is no work around exposed via the puppeteer api but there is a cdp command that would make it possible.

I guess my question is does that sound correct in terms of state of affairs and what would the reason be for not including frames in the accessibility tree? I see the same behaviour in devtools but that can't be true for the speech browsers as they do see inside frames!

I'm thinking raise a bug/feature to add something like `frame.accessibility.snapshot()` or is this a bug in chrome that it doesn't return iframes in the full tree.

Same with aria/selectors is there a good reason to keep frames separate or should I be asking for that to be looked at again?